# Deploying Client Software via GPO - Will server reboot affect?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have deployed a MSI file via a GPO to one of my AD OUs. For an MSI to install via the GPO, I know the clients need to be rebooted.

I have planned a reboot for the clients, but I was also planning on rebooting the server at the same time. The clients have already synced with the server to obtain this GPO as well as another that has scheduled their reboot time.

What I'm wondering is, will the clients be able to install the software, during their reboot, when the server is also down? I would assume that they would have obtained the MSI when they did their daily sync of group policy with the DC, but I can't find anything to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The msi source share/folder needs to be accessible when the GPO is applied to the client machine and it attempts to install the software.  I would let your client machines do their installs before you reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous post, either do your client upgrades first, then reboot them, or your server first +reboot, then the clients. Knowing how Microsoft technologies don't like their network connections messed with, your suspicion is correct.